# how to get some particular words from a line using cut command

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with the following text

and I want to get the 1st,2nd,and 4th value only`**1343311371204**,*****210*****,http://172.16.1.139/CC_WEB/jsp/Login.jsp,**200**,OK,true,9,9
1343311371044,304,http://172.16.1.139/CC_WEB/jsp/Login.jsp,200,OK,true,8,8
1343311371109,239,http://172.16.1.139/CC_WEB/jsp/Login.jsp,200,OK,true,8,8
1343311371083,263,http://172.16.1.139/CC_WEB/jsp/Login.jsp,200,OK,true,8,8` in every line. So How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using cut

`cut -d, -f1,2,4 your_file` should do it fine.

## Using read (bash builtin function)

Using read in a while loop, you can use variables to do things with those values :

```
while IFS=',' read timestamp value2 url code remains ; do
    # use those variables
done < your_file`
```

Comment: No Need of cat, just `cut -d, -f1,2,4 file ` is enough

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$4}' your_file
```